# How to exclude livereload dependency from NestJS/Angular Universal?

Tags: angular, security, nestjs, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I do have an application with Server-Side Rendering (SSR) using Angular Universal, and NestJS. The focus is a lot on security. When I deploy it using [Sucuri Sitecheck](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/) I can see that the http://localhost:35729/livereload.js is included in this (this scanner throws information **only** about this script). And this is over unencrypted HTTP, which I don't want. I can see that Subresource Integrity in [Mozilla Observatory](https://observatory.mozilla.org/) also gives me -50 points for loading external scripts over HTTP. Is there any way to exclude this script from a compilation bundle? Below is my code.

```
AngularUniversalModule.forRoot({
  bundle: require('path/to/server/main'),
  liveReload: true,
  templatePath: join(BROWSER_DIR, 'index2.html'),
  viewsPath: BROWSER_DIR
})
```

I did try to remove **liveReload: true** from **AngularUniversalModule**, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently removing `liveReload: true` from **AngularUniversalModule** solved this problem, it looks like I had to wait for some time to get the updated results from the browser/scanner